# Class cast exception between parent and child classes

Tags: android, kotlin

I waas develop an app in kotlin, when I get to the following error:

[image]

rise by the following check in the first line:

```
(it.responseBase as ValidateOtpResponse).let {resp ->  // error rise here
                            if (resp.code == "200") {
                                val sucessDialog = GenericDialog(
                                    context = requireContext(),
                                    icon = R.drawable.ic_tick_green,
                                    title = getString(R.string.change_password_title),
                                    subtitle = getString(R.string.password_change_sucess),
                                    buttonText = getString(R.string.understand),
                                    cancelable = true,
                                    clickListener = { (activity as DashboarActivity).redirectToLogin() }
                                )
                                sucessDialog.show(requireFragmentManager(), "sucess_otp_dialog")
                            } else {
                                showOtpError().also {
                                    (activity as DashboarActivity).redirectToLogin()
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

and the arquitecture of the clases in the app is this:

```
data class ValidateOtpResponse(
    @SerializedName("code")
    val code: String
) : Serializable, ResponseBase()
```

and their parent:

```
open class ResponseBase : Serializable
```

Have this any sense? Because I being using this kind of cast along the app, and it's works until now

So if you can throw some light into this issue, take thanks in advance !

Comment: The error seems to suggest you got a `ResponseBase` instance, not a `ValidateOtpResponse` instance, so the exception would appear to make perfect sense. You need to figure out why `it.responseBase` is not what you expected.

Comment: By the way, [same comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72818194/class-cast-exception-between-parent-and-child-classes?noredirect=1#comment128622077_72818903)

Comment: Casting is working only from Child-class to Parent-class, not the opposite

Comment: @AimanAlyosofi Not sure I understand what you're trying to say. Casting from child to parent is an "up-cast". In pretty much any sensible language, up-casting typically does not require any explicit code. But the opposite, going from parent to child, is a "down-cast". That's what most people are talking about when they talk about "casting". It's also the only time a `ClassCastException` could be thrown in Java/Kotlin (an invalid up-cast would result in a compilation error instead of a run-time error).

Answer (score -1):

Your response is of type ResponseBase which is the superclass. You are trying to cast it to type ValidateOtpResponse which is a subclass. You would not be able to cast an object of superclass into an object of the subclass.

For example:
[image: snippet for examples]

You need to fetch the response of type ValidateOtpResponse.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) (also applies to answers)